# Calling stored procedure from Entity Framework 3.5

Tags: entity-framework

I"m using VS 2010 & EF 3.5. I've imported a stored procedure which returns a list of guids using the `Function Import` feature. How do I invoke it in my code? After instantiating the `dbcontext`, intellisense doesn't display the procedure I've imported. I know it's pretty easy in EF 4.0 but I'm stuck with EF 3.5 for this project. Any ideas on how get around this other than doing it the old-fashioned way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think EF versions prior to 4 can use imported stored procedures that don't return entities. That is, your stored procedure must return a complete entity object in order for EF to use it. Since your procedure only returns a list of GUIDs, EF doesn't know how to use it.

You can put this in your partial data-context class to call the procedure:

```
    public IEnumerable<Guid> GetMyGUIDs()
    {
        if (this.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            this.Connection.Open();
        var command = new System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommand
        {
            CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            CommandText = @"YourContext.YourProcedureName",
            Connection = (System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection)this.Connection
        };
        var list = new List<Guid>();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // get GUID values from the reader here,
            // and put them in the list

            reader.Close();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. So I need to put in your code in a method in the partial class and return DbDataReader? I thought DataReader cannot be return from a method since it needs to be connected to the DB. Could you please paste complete code? Thank you very much.

Comment: @enigma -- See the updated example. You can do whatever you want with the reader, and you can return whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. How do I make it generic? I have a few other procedures to call which returns custom object with multiple columns (join from different tables).

Comment: I should be able to extract the DataTable out of the DataReader and return it instead. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Also, I couldn't find the raw EDMX file in the project or in the file system. Is it not generated for EF 3.5?

Comment: The raw .edmx file, by default, opens in the designer in Visual Studio. To see its raw XML, open it with a text editor, or right click -> Open With -> XML Editor.